# Django advanced filter is not working with django jet

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-jet, django-advanced-filters

When I installed Django advanced filter, the option of the advanced filter is not showing in the admin. I have removed the Django jet then it is running well.

Anyone having a solution to run Django advanced filter with Django jet?

Comment: Have you considered raising this issue on the issue trackers for either or both projects?

Comment: No, I haven't raised the issue.